# how to stream mp3 file in iphone?

Tags: stream, mp3, avaudioplayer

I'm streaming my mp3 file but it is starting very very late

after launch the application i have to wait for 1 or 2 mints then it plays the music

why it is so ?

can anybody have an idea ?

Please Do Tell me how can i play direct track without waiting too long

here what i m doing with my code in `viewDidLoad` method

```
-(void)viewDidLoad

{

   NSString *urlstr=@"http://media.hyderabadplus.com/naats/Aamir Liaquat Hussain - Panjtan Ko Salaam/Ramzan Assalam.MP3";

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlstr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   NSData *songData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

   self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:songData error:nil];

   self.audioPlayer.numberOfLoops=0;

   self.audioPlayer.delegate=self;

   [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

   [self.audioPlayer play];

}
```